# How to make a method accessible to one user at a time in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I am currently working on an e-commerce website. I'm having a strange problem with the payment portion.

In my method, I wrote logic to compare a user's quantity to the available quantity. If the user quantity exceeds the available quantity, my method logic redirects the user to the cart section.

If the available quantity exceeds the user quantity, my logic moves the user to the payment section. My logic is functioning well.

However, when only one product is available and two or more customers click on the paynow button at the same time, my logic compares the quantity of both users at the same time with the available quantity at this time the 1 quantity is available is available for the users and my logic allow the user for payment which is not good.

After that my table's available quantity column becomes negative as a result of this process, which is not desirable.

Does anyone have an idea how to address this problem? Or any other option is available to limit my method to a single call at a time type?

If anyone has a suggestion, please share it with me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Checking and decreasing must be done in a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions). Note that the mutual exclusion must happen in the DB, not in the method and this is what the transaction does.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your advice. Please reassure me that if I implement mutual exclusion in the crucial area and it only permits one request at a time, the speed of my website won't be affected.

Comment: If two apps or two threads want to access these records at the same time, then one of them will have to wait for a fraction of a second. Otherwise, the impact of transactions is barely measurable or can even improve performance. But it always depends on the concrete case. So, the only way to find out is: measure, measure, measure! But even if slows down the site: If a transaction is required for correctness it **must** be done!